# Can Java Block Open TCP ports?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

E.g i am trying to build a software which can block TCP ports *by my choice* which are being used by applications. Is there any means to accomplish such?

Comment: What exactly does "blocking" mean in this context? Denial of Service via SYN flood? And do you want to block local or remote ports? In the former case, your program will essentially be a host-based firewall, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "block"?

Comment: What do you mean by "block"?  Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Ok, This is the scenario. I will simulate a DDOS attack on Port 5000  using an application. Normally i should be able to view the network activity on netstat including the port number ie if its not spoofed. So this application should have some input box which if i enter port 5000, it blocks the port. Do u get the idea?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "block" a TCP port for a Java program is to open its own server on the like, so no other software can use this port anymore.

If you want to implement a firewall, you have to use the specialised APIs of your operating system, like ipchains on linux, or [the corresponsing windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This API is also used by the windows firewall and all other firewalls on windows.

This however needs native code, so have a look at JNA or JNI.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply.Its indeed very informative. So does it mean with Java JNA or JNI i can be able to block already opened ports by other applications?  E.g block port 5000  used by an application called Trinoo if its used by a hacker to DOS my computer?

Comment: Thats what I firewall is for I guess. I think you even can handle the "open"-event when the app tries to open the port, and handle it by saying "no" to the app.

Comment: I am not sure is a firewall can force the closure of an existing connection.  Even if you block an open connection in a hardware firewall, it will leave the connection open (as it prevents even the close packet, until it times out naturally)

Comment: You will have to completely drop traffic to the target host, this is right. Usually you just drop the initiation of a connection.